# Using LIKE with % and Parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameters, wildcard, sql-like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ModuleReferenceCount]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @module     nvarchar(255)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT COUNT([dbo].[Slots].[ObjectID])
    FROM [Slots]
    *WHERE [dbo].[Slots].[SlotValue] LIKE CONCAT(%%//, @module, %%)*
END
GO
```

This is what I have right now. The line in question is line 4 of the code portion, and is between ** (** not there in actual code). I have tried not using CONCAT and using multiple configurations with 'xyz', using = instead of like, etc. I don't think I am grasping the syntax properly, but if possible I want to check for (info)//(userdefined module name)(info) where info can be effectively anything, and (userdefined module name) is my parameter; so something like: abc//module1.xyz or lmn//module22//qrs

Thanks!

Comment: What is `%%//` mean to be doing exactly? `%` is a modulo operator, and doesn't make sense there, and the `/` isn't an operator at all. If you want to wrap the value in pattern wild cards, you would use `'%'`. Where did you see the syntax you have, as it's not in any documentation or articles I've seen

Comment: I want that part to be % '//'; When I just put % it says "Expecting %" regardless of what I put after the first %, so I thought having %% might be necessary. I want to be read by the computer as "(Wildcard)//" when I type %%//

Comment: So why not `'%/'`? Or `'%/%'`? You aren't clear you what you want here. What about the wild cards confuse you here? `%` in the string value matches *any number* of characters, and `_` within the string matches a single character. What about these 2 confuses you?

Comment: I want "% followed by // followed by the parameter (@module) followed by %" I am not sure of how to do this, which is the entire reason why I am posting this question.

Comment: `'%//'`... Again, the problem seems to be that you don't understand the wildcards; what confuses you here?

Comment: That is all I was asking; if I put `LIKE CONCAT('%//', @module, '%')` it does not give me any errors. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: But do you understand now..?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ModuleReferenceCount]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@module     nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.

SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @searchtext AS NVARCHAR(255)
SET @searchtext='%'+@module+'%'

SELECT COUNT([dbo].[Slots].[ObjectID])
FROM [Slots]
WHERE [dbo].[Slots].[SlotValue] LIKE @searchtext
END
GO
```

Comment: This could have worked, too; I ended up using
 `WHERE [dbo].[Slots].[SlotValue] LIKE CONCAT('%//', @module,'/%')`